# How to generate and correlate more than two random variables which are from different non-parametric distributions given then correlation matrix?

Tags: distributions, correlation, simulation

I tried to fit three variables using the non-parametric method(kernel smooth), and those distribution for each of three variables are different, so cholesky descomposition won´t work for replicate the correlation calculated by the historical data when i´m trying to make a simulation. 
    And I need a way to simulate these variables which meets follow requirements:

1. Each simulated variable should still follow it´s fitted non parametric 
     distribution.
2. Correlation should be replicated.

Anyone has an idea? I´ll apreciate.

Zhe

Comment: Please see the hits at [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula+simulat*+correl*+answers%3A1).

Comment: Hi Whuber,I just read these 2 questions posted by you which you think similar to mine, and I think no answers were about simulation for several differente non-parametric simulation. In the first one you posted,there´s no distribution limit and the second is about 2 normal distribution variable simulation. Neither will work for me, please review my question, Thanks a lot

Comment: Please, then, edit your post to clarify what you are looking for: that will help distinguish your problem from the apparently related ones.

Comment: Hi, I think the need of replicating fitted non parametric distribution has been clarified to distinguish from others correlation problems.

Comment: If that's really your question, then you can find answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=generate+kernel+density+random.

Comment: Look, I´v edited my question, which clarifies 2 needs,the first is simulate non parametric distribution variables and the second is to correlate these simulated variables. I think what you just posted  meets the first need and you had posted before  explains how to correlate normal distribution variables,but not for correlating non parametric distribution variables

Comment: Should i make more modification to unlock the "Duplicated"?

Comment: Because all the essential components of your question appear to have been addressed in other threads, it would help to articulate where you are looking for help in assembling the solutions.

Comment: Understand,I will try to improve my questions